# In Haxe, how do you pass Enum values in functions, and then convert them to Strings within the function?

Tags: string, enums, parameter-passing, haxe

I can't seem to get this working, but I'd be surprised if it wasn't possible in Haxe.

I'm trying to pass a couple of Enum values defined in my game to a function, so that it can then concatenate them as `String` types and pass that to other functions.

Example:

```
// In a general Entity class:
public override function kill():Void {
    messages.dispatchCombined(entityType, ListMessages.KILLED);

    super.kill();
}
```

And in my Messages.hx class:

```
package common;

import msignal.Signal.Signal1;

/**
 * A Message / Event class using Signals bound to String names.
 * @author Pierre Chamberlain
 */
class Messages{
    var _messages:MessagesDef;

    public function new() {
        _messages = new MessagesDef();
    }

    public function add(pType:String, pCallback:FuncDef) {
        if (_messages[pType] == null) {
            _messages[pType] = new Signal1<Dynamic>();
        }

        var signals = _messages[pType];
        signals.add( pCallback );
    }

    public function dispatch(pType:String, pArg:Dynamic):Bool {
        var signals = _messages[pType];
        if (signals == null) return false;
        signals.dispatch(pArg);
        return true;
    }

    //Compiler doesn't like passing enums :(
    public inline function addCombined(pSource:Enum, pEvent:Enum, pCallback:FuncDef) {
        add( combine(pSource, pEvent), pCallback );
    }

    public inline function dispatchCombined(pSource:Enum, pEvent:Enum, pArg:Dynamic):Bool {
        return dispatch( combine(pSource, pEvent), pArg);
    }

    //How can I just pass the enum "names" as strings?
    static inline function combine(a:Enum, b:Enum):String {
        return String(a) + ":" + String(b);
    }
}


typedef MessagesDef = Map<String, Signal1<Dynamic>>;
typedef FuncDef = Dynamic->Void;
```

Note how **`addCombined`, `dispatchCombined`** and **`combine`** expect an "Enum" type, but in this case I'm not sure if Haxe actually expects the entire Enum "class" to be passed (ie: `ListMessages` instead of `ListMessages.KILLED`) or if a value should work. Anyways, compiler doesn't like it - so I'm assuming another special Type has to be used.

Is there another way to go about passing enums and resolving them to strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Dynamic instead of Enum or pass them as Strings right away since you can always convert to enum from String if you need it later.

Anyway pass the enum as enum:Dynamic and then call Std.string(enum);

EDIT: Using EnumValue is definitely better approach than Dynamic, I use Dynamic in these functions because I send more than just Enums there and I am not worried about type safety in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution! Forgot how `Dynamic` is the superman of Haxe.

Comment: Please, don't use `Dynamic` if there are better solutions http://try.haxe.org/#80108

Answer (score 5):

I think you need [EnumValue](http://api.haxe.org/EnumValue.html) as parameter type (if it is only for enum values), and use [Std.String](http://api.haxe.org/Std.html#string) to convert to String values.

```
static inline function combine(a:EnumValue, b:EnumValue):String {
    return Std.string(a) + ":" + Std.string(b);
}
```

Of course that can be written smaller using [String interpolation](http://haxe.org/manual/lf-string-interpolation.html):

```
static inline function combine(a:EnumValue, b:EnumValue):String {
    return '$a:$b';
}
```

Of course that can be 'more dynamic' using [type parameters](http://haxe.org/manual/type-system-type-parameters.html):

```
static inline function combine<A, B>(a:A, b:B):String {
    return '$a:$b';
}
```

There is totally no need to use Dynamic as suggested. If you use Dynamic, you basically [turn off the type system](http://haxe.org/manual/types-dynamic.html).

**live example:**
http://try.haxe.org/#a8844

Comment: Better constrain the type parameters as <A:EnumValue, B:EnumValue>

Comment: Yes, if you want to, since it's about to-string conversion, one maybe want other types too.